# Android Debug Key/Keystore changed, can't find origin of new one

Tags: android, facebook, hash

I recently went to update an app I have that uses Facebook login. This has been working with no problems both in debug and release. The matching Facebook app has both hashes for the debug key and the release key.

So after I made some changes and started a debug session, I discover that the Facebook login wasn't working. Upon reviewing the error, it told me that the hash key used did not match any of the hash keys on the Facebook app.

ApiException:Key hash xxxx...xxxx does not match any stored key hashes

I went through the steps again [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) to check the debug key hash, and indeed it is different from any of the ones in the FB app. **HOWEVER, it is also different from the one given in the Exception above.**

I have "solved" this by just saving that hash from the Exception into the FB App, but I would like to understand the following:

1) Why did the hash for the debug key suddenly change? If I redo the hash, it doesn't match the old debug hash key I have in my FB App. (I did update the Android SDK a couple days before starting this update, could that change the debug keystore/key?)

2) Where is the that hash from the Exception coming from. It doesn't match the hash generated from the keystore at ~/.android/debug.keystore, so where is it actually coming from?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you wiped out your Android SDK folder, you may have generated a new debug keystore (Android Studio and Eclipse will both generate one at compile time if it doesn't exist).  This would explain what you were seeing.

Comment: I don't see how the folder could have been wiped out if that is what happened. When you mentioned Android Studio I remembered that I installed it a few days ago, but I also checked the debug.keystore file and it says created and modified this past Sept 1st. That's well before I installed Android Studio or updated the SDK, so no idea what went on there. I did discover that the mismatch of the hashes I mentioned was because I was not using the correct password for debug.keystore (the default "android"). Using that, the hash comes out the same as the one in the Exception, mystery is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short:

1) The hash changed because the debug.keystore was recreated. The exact reason why it was recreated is not clear, but it is not the point. Bottom line, the keystore was recreated, the debug key changed, and therefore the hash changed.

2) The hash was actually coming from that recreated keystore. Problem was that when creating the hash I wasn't using the proper keystore password (the default one: "android") and that was messing the hash. With the proper password to the kesytore, the hashes did match.